# How can I install bind-utils on El Capitan

Tags: macos, command-line, dns

I would like to use DNSSEC tools (like `dnssec-keygen`, `dnssec-signzone`, ...) on my Mac without running or installing the BIND9 service.

Unfortunately for me Homebrew seems only to have the BIND9 package, but not bind-utils
The official website https://www.isc.org/downloads/ also doesn't provide these tools.

Can someone know how I can use these tools on Mac ?

Comment: I just downloaded https://github.com/tigeli/bind-utils and ran `bind-utils-master $ ./configure` and `make` and then in `bind-utils-master/bin/dnssec/` there was `dnssec-keygen` and `dnssec-signzone` as well as all the other bind-utils that were built in the `bind-utils-master $` directory structure.  You need to have Command Line Tools for Xcode installed.

Comment: Thanks @user3439894. The link you provided doesn't seems official, but at the bottom of the page there is a link to the official git of BIND9 http://www.isc.org/git/ where all tools are also here.

Comment: I got the following error : `checking for OpenSSL... configure error "/usr/bin/openssl/include/openssl/opensslv.h" not found`, So I installed openssl with `brew install openssl` and next  `./configure --with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl/`. Now it's working great.